# Iterating through a vector of pointers to classes

Tags: c++, class, pointers, iterator

so I have an issue where I am trying to get coordinates of a ship and return a pointer. However I'm getting an issue where the compiler is not detecting the private variables i created for my ship class.

in my .h files.

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H
#include "Ship.h"
#include<vector>
class Board
{

  private:
    std::vector<Ship *> shipList;
    char score[10][10];
    Ship *shipAt(int x, int y);
};
#endif
```

relevant variables in my ship.h file

```
private: 
int x1,y1,x2,y2;
```

My function

```
Ship *Board::shipAt (int x, int y){

    vector <Ship*> :: iterator locate; //locating the appropiate ship with this iterator

    for ( locate = shipList.begin(); locate != shipList.end() ; locate++ ){
            if( *locate.x1 == *locate.x2){
                    if(( y <= *locate.y1 && y >= *locate.y2) || (y <= *locate.y2 && y >= *locate.y1)){
                            return locate;
                    }
            }

            else if ( *locate.y1 == *locate.y2){
                            if(( x <= *locate.x1 && x >= *locate.x2) || ( x <= *locate.x2 && *locate.x1)){
                                    return locate;
                            }
                    }
    }
}


 I'm getting the error

 Board.cpp:54:15: error: ‘std::vector<Ship*>::iterator’ has no member named ‘x1’
   if( *locate.x1 == *locate.x2){
           ^
Board.cpp:54:29: error: ‘std::vector<Ship*>::iterator’ has no member named ‘x2’
   if( *locate.x1 == *locate.x2){
```

Comment: those members are private, make Board a friend, and use `(*locate)->`

Comment: `*locate.x1` is really `*(locate.x1)`, not `(*locate).x1`. Your iterator points to a pointer, so you want to use `(*(*locate)).x1` or the overloaded `->` operator to make it pretty: `(*locate)->x1`. Also, you're returning `locate`, which is an iterator, not a `Ship*`.

Comment: Shouldn't your `Ship` class tell the whole world where it is?  Why is there no `public` function(s) to return the Ship's coordinates?

Comment: Paul, I have all of those functions. I just took parts of my header files that are relevant for the function at hand.

Answer (score 2):

The first issue you have is operator precedence. You're trying to dereference `locate.x1` when in reality what you wanted to do is first dereference `locate` to get the pointer, and then access the `x1` member. So the code you want is `(*locate).x1` (see next paragraph)

Then you have two other problems. Since you have a pointer, and thus to access `x1` you need to use `->`, not a '`.`'.

Finally you'll run into visibility issues, since `x1` is private.

The error message gives you a good diagnostic:

> error: ‘std::vector<Ship*>::iterator’ has no member named ‘x2’

The compiler is telling you that the `iterator` type has no member `x2`, which should be a hint that you're trying to access `x2` from the wrong type of object. You are trying to access the x2 from a `Ship`.

Answer (score 1):

Although frozenkoi 's answer is good, you might be interested in the following issues.

1. Don't use pointers. Use smart pointers, e.g. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm
2. Remember the difference between pre- and post-increment. Always use pre-in/decrement with iterators!
3. Use well-known algorithms to solve well-known and well-documented problems. In your case [Point inside rectangle test](https://www.google.pl/search?client=opera&q=testing%20if%20point%20is%20in%20rectangle&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest)

Answer (score 0):

neater, easier to read:

```
Ship* Board::shipAt (int x, int y)
{
    for ( auto s : shipList )
    {
        if( x < min(s->x1,s->x2) ) continue;
        if( x > max(s->x1,s->x2) ) continue;
        if( y < min(s->y1,s->y2) ) continue;
        if( y > max(s->y1,s->y2) ) continue;
        return s;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: what does the auto keyword do? I've never seen anything like it.

Comment: figures out the type automaticly